# Error in wxwidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

```
#pragma once
#include "Tool.h"

#include "Rectangle.h"

class Rectangle;
class RectangleTool :
    public Tool
{
public:
    RectangleTool();
    ~RectangleTool();
    virtual void ToolMouseLeftDown(wxMouseEvent &event);
    virtual void ToolMouseLeftUp(wxMouseEvent &event);
    virtual void ToolMouseMotion(wxMouseEvent &event);
private:
    Rectangle *rectangle;
};
```

the error massage is:

```
function "Rectangle" is not type of name
```

What should I do?

Comment: That error must be coming from one of the headers, not the code in your post.
It's also from your code which apparently uses wxWidgets, but not "in wxwidgets".

Comment: I doubt that's the actual error message. What is the actual error message precisely?

Comment: I guess this is something to do with your cpp file rather than header. If I were you, I would try deleting inclusion of Rectangle.h and include it in the cpp file.